# The intersection of all Levi factors

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb R$ and let $\mathbb s$ be a Levi factor, i.e, a maximal semisimple Lie subalgebra. Since Levi factors are conjugate to each other, what is the intersection of all these conjugation subalgebras? i.e, what is the intersection of all Levi factors? Can it be trivial?

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned so far, let me mention that (1) $\mathfrak{g}$ is implicitly assumed finite-dimensional, otherwise the question doesn't make sense (2) this intersection is also the largest semisimple ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$ (3) this holds true under an arbitrary field of characteristic zero. (4) it can be trivial, e.g. if $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable, but not only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since two Levi factors are always conjugate by an inner automorphism, the intersection of all conjugates of a Levi factor $\mathfrak q$ is equal to
$$
\mathfrak h =\bigcap_{g\in G}\operatorname{Ad}_g(\mathfrak q)
$$
Therefore, $\mathfrak h$ is invariant under all one-parameter subgroups, so by differentiating $\operatorname{Ad}$ we see that it is an ideal in $\mathfrak g$.

Now, we claim that this ideal is exactly the centraliser of the solvable radical $\operatorname{rad}\mathfrak g$ in $\mathfrak q$.

Indeed, clearly $\mathfrak h\cap \operatorname{rad}\mathfrak g = \{0\}$, so for $h\in\mathfrak h$, $x\in\operatorname{rad}\mathfrak g$ we get $[h,x]=0$.

On the other hand, by a result of Mal'cev two Levi factors are conjugate by an inner automorphism coming from the nilradical (so in the above formula it's enough to conjugate by $g= \exp(x)$ for $x\in\operatorname{nil}\mathfrak g$). Therefore, if $h$ commutes with the radical, it's acted trivially upon by the nilradical and hence is in $\mathfrak h$.

Comment: thanks.  What  does "commutant" mean?  The centerlizer? So it is not possible to $\mathfrak h $ to be trivial?

Comment: Yes, the centraliser (commutant is a synonym); I also added to the answer that the centraliser has to be taken in the Levi part (I forgot to write that explicitly). It is very well possible for $\mathfrak h$ to be trivial: say, in the “$ax+b$” Lie algebra (the Lie algebra of the Lie group $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$) the “$b$” part is maximal abelian, so nothing nontrivial in the Levi part can commute with it. On the other extreme, if the whole $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple, then $\mathfrak h = \mathfrak g$.

Comment: The Mal'cev theorem you mentioned is very interesting. Just to make sure that I understand it well: In Lie group theory, the theorem implies that, a Levi factor $S$ of a Lie group $G$ is normal iff $nSn^{−1}=S$ for all n in the nil-radical N of G? and if we neglect the center then we only need to check $n\in R'$?   Thanks

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell this is the correct Lie group version of it.

Comment: Thanks Vadim! My observation about neglecting the center is okay too?

Comment: Well, the centre of $G$ can be neglected anyway. As for $R$ (I guess, it's the solvable radical?), I'm not quite sure what you mean: $R$ might be itself abelian and then one truly has to check whether it normalises $S$ or not, $R'$ is then not enough (and in general the solvable radical might coincide with the nilradical).

Comment: yes $R$ is the solvable radical. But if $R$ is abelian then its central in $G$ and its elements stabilize all subgroups?? I am missing something?

Comment: If $R$ is abelian, it need not be central: think of the “$Ax+b$” group where $A\in\operatorname{SO}(n)$  (the semidirect product of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ and $\mathbb R^n$) for $n\geqslant 3$: its solvable radical is $\mathbb R^n$, but it is by no means central.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for asking too much! But I still have one last question about  $\mathfrak h$ in your answer. Is this ideal a characteristic ideal of $\mathfrak g$? Or at least, if $\mathfrak p\lhd \mathfrak h$, is $\mathfrak p\lhd \mathfrak g$? I appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is: of course, $\mathfrak h$ is also the intersection of conjugates of $\mathfrak q$ by _all_ automorphisms of $\mathfrak g$, not just inner ones, so again by differentiating we see that it is invariant under all derivations of $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: Thanks Vadim :) and happy new year!